# PHP Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in

Tags: php

There is the problem with

```
$bg_img_size = getimagesize($canon_options_appearance['bg_img_url']);
```

Due to this problem my server is create an problem with the speed issue the code is below.

```
/* BACKGROUND */

        body{
            <?php if (!empty($canon_options_appearance['bg_img_url'])) echo 'background-image: url("' . $canon_options_appearance['bg_img_url'] . '")!important;'; ?>
            <?php if (isset($canon_options_appearance['bg_repeat'])) echo 'background-repeat: ' . $canon_options_appearance['bg_repeat'] . '!important;'; ?>
            <?php if (isset($canon_options_appearance['bg_attachment'])) echo 'background-attachment: ' . $canon_options_appearance['bg_attachment'] .'!important;'; ?>
            background-position: top center;
            <?php if (isset($canon_options_appearance['bg_link'])) { if (!empty($canon_options_appearance['bg_link'])) { echo "cursor: pointer;"; } } ;?>
        }
```

Comment: what you've got so far?

Comment: If you do a var_dump() on $canon_options_appearance['bg_img_url'] what do you get?

Comment: body div { cursor: auto; }

   <?php 

    if ($canon_options_appearance['bg_size'] == "pattern") : 

    $bg_img_size = getimagesize($canon_options_appearance['bg_img_url']);
    $bg_img_width = round($bg_img_size[0] / 2);
    $bg_img_height = round($bg_img_size[1] / 2);

   ?>

Comment: how do i reslove this problem